# Jquery <tr> and id elements

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I am new to Jquery and wondered if I can give a  an ID and if so how can I then get the value back .
The best I have come up with so for is

```
  rid = $('tr').attr('id').val()
```

but no luck ......

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), just use this:

```
var rid = $('tr').attr('id');
```

[`.attr('attributeName')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) returns a string (in most cases) of the attribute, [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is for getting the value from input type elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

To set the value:

```
$('tr').attr('id', 'someValue');
```

To get the value:

```
var id = $('tr').attr('id');
```